# Why am I getting a java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Tags: java, exception, buffer-overflow

I tried to create a simple program just for fun, but I'm getting a BufferOverflowException:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(10);
FloatBuffer floatBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
floatBuffer.put(new float[] {1, 0, 0});
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(10);` you ask for allocating 10 bytes of memory. You are then putting 3 `float` in that buffer. Each float uses 4 bytes of memory as per [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). So you are using 12 bytes and thus the overflow.

To solve the problem just use 12 bytes instead of 10.